Database and visual studio code connection issuess
For context, I'm making a programming (using C#) that acts similar to a website. Where in this website, it will show any vendor that sells a product or service within the dormitory area in university. and the user are able to view and search any vendor's that provide goods or services he/she want it. Which then, the user will be given the contact of teh vendor and able to interact with the vendor in an external application (Whatsapp). when the user starts the program, the program will display the main menu. the main menu have 4 sections that user can choose from in the main menu interface (Food and drink, Clothes, miscellaneous and exit). if the user chooses the first three option, the program supposed to display a table of data that are obtained from the database that is connected to the visual studio code. and after displaying the table, the program will loop back itself into the main menu of the program. and if the user choose the fourth option, it will end the program.
when i test my program and select one of the first three section (i chose food and drink option), the program won't show the table (it supposed to show the food_and_drink table) instead display an error message of "Error: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)". and after the error message, the program loops back to the main menu again. and this error goes for all of the first three option.
note: 1. for the database, im using myphpadmin (through xampp) to manage and store the database.

The database has 6 tables:


Tenant_list table (hold information about the vendor personal details)

dormitory_building table (hold information about the building that the vendor lives in)

product_junction table (the junction table to connect the table between the vendor an dthe product he/her is selling)

food_and_drink table (hold the information for the product details that is related to food and drinks)

clothing_table (hold the information for the product details that is related to clothing)


-Miscellaneous table (hold the information for the product details that is related to anything then from food & drinks or clothing)

the extension (in visual studio code) that i used to connect the database to visual studio code is called "MySQL" created by Weijan Chen

i already modify the privilege of the root user (since i used root user to handle the database in myphpadmin) and also changed my authentication plugin to mysql_native_password (i actually didn't changed, is that the plugin already set up that way)


the coding (C# language):
using System;
 using System.Threading;
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void DisplayTableData(string tableName)
        {
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=telyu_vendor_dorm;User ID=root;";
            string query = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";

            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                    {
                        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Data from table '{tableName}':");
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        Console.Write($"{reader.GetName(i)}: {reader[i]}  ");
                                    }
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"No data found in table '{tableName}'.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        static void Foodie()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Food and Drink category!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            DisplayTableData("Food_and_Drink");
        }

        static void Clothes()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Clothing category!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            DisplayTableData("Clothes");
        }

        static void TheOtherStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen the Miscellaneous category!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            DisplayTableData("Miscellaneous");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int itsTimeToStop = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Telkom University Dormitory Market (test version)");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("What do you want to do today?");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            while (itsTimeToStop < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" | [1] Food and Drinks | [2] Clothing | [3] Miscellaneous | [4] Exit");
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.Write("Your chosen category: ");
                int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Foodie();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Clothes();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        TheOtherStuff();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("You have exited the website!");
                        itsTimeToStop++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a valid option.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


The error message implies that your connection string is't whata is expected (probably you need a password) Not anithing wrong with your code

This question is similar to: How to form a correct MySQL connection string?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Seems like issue persists because of your connectionString, it should be like.
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=your_database;User=your_username;Password=your_password;SslMode=none;"

Note:- if still facing the same error make sure you have installed MySql.Data package, if already installed than update it to latest as per the release with your dotnet core version.

Thank you for your tip. i already tried to rewrite  code for the "connection String" same as yours. unfortunately, it stills produces an error message instead of displaying the table
The error message: "Error: Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'Telyu_VendorDorm' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'Telyu_VendorDorm'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
the following modified line of code:  string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=telyu_vendor_dorm;User ID=Telyu_VendorDorm;Password=MYSQLTELKOM;SslMode=none";

@UnknownWanderer1995 If the program will log in with user id Telyu_VendorDorm then you need to configure MySQL to allow login of this id from localhost, with the correct password.
